# Using Microsoft Graph client sdk how would you use search Odata query

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft Graph client sdk how would one go about using search Odata query to lookup if subject or body contains a certain search term.

The $search Odata query parameter is available in the Graph Client api, but i could not find how to use the parameter using the client sdk for c#.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add any query parameters by passing in a list of `QueryOptions` to the `Request` method.

```
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
     new QueryOption("$search", "lunch")
};
var messages = await client.Me.Messages.Request(options).GetAsync();
```

Documentation: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md#custom-query-options

Comment: Thank you i was looking for this in the documentation, but didn't find it.

Comment: One more thing, when i search with "subject:pizza" or "from:help@contoso.com" as specified in the outlook mail api i get an error stating that the ":" character is not valid.

Comment: Just needed to surround the search term with double quotes in the string itself. I had to escape double quotes with a \ like so; string term =  "\"subject:pizza\"".

Comment: Great! Glad you got this working, let us know if you need any more help. I'll also pass the feedback to the team that we should support a helper method for $search like we do for $filter and other OData query params so you don't have to pass in a custom query option.

Comment: This has been added to the documentation: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md#custom-query-options

Comment: Is there a possible way to change the subject of a reply email

Comment: @JohnStaurt would you mind asking that as a separate question with the microsoftgraph tag so all the people watching that tag get notified and can help?

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking off of @JohnStaurt's comments above, this worked for me:

```
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
     new QueryOption("$search", "\"displayName:team\" OR \"description:team\"")
};
```